# Write a formula for $z^*$ with respect to line $l=\{ax+by=c\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Write a formula for $z^*$ with respect to line $l=\{ax+by=c\}$. ($z^*$ is the symmetric point of $z$ with respect to $l$) At first, I thought of solving it like I used to in High-School, but then recalled we were just learning about Mobius transformations and thought I better approach it with analogy to the real line, with is the simpler case. The thing is: I really don't manage to find a proper Mobius transformation. I try to take arguments and the origin into account but it just won't go very well. What do I do with the origin? Maybe it is all just a misconception of the whole subject? Have some of you got any idea as for how to correctly approach this in terms of the complex analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should write the line $l$ in terms of $z$ instead of $x$ and $y$:
$$
  ax + by + c = a\frac{z + \overline z}{2} + b \frac{z - \overline z}{2i} \\
  = \frac 12 \left( (a-ib)z + (a+ib) \bar z\right) + c
 = \text{Re} ( Az + c) = \text{Im}(i(Az+c))
$$
with $A := a - ib$.

So the (linear) Möbius transformation $w = i(Az +c)$
transforms the line $l$ to the real axis $ \text{Im}(w) = 0$.
The symmetric point of $w$ with respect to the real axis
is $w^* = \overline w$. Then transform $w^*$ back to $z^*$.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. You really helped me understand it better. Just still wondering how it can be seen as a mobius transformation. Is $Ai=a$ in the mobius coefficients?

Comment: @Meitar: Yes, $w = \frac{(iA)z + (ic)}{0z + 1}$.

Comment: Terrifically demonstrated.

Comment: Hypothetical question: we did we need to add this $i$? Could we add $-i$ instead? Is that so that the imaginary part will disappear?

Comment: @Meitar: there are many different ways to solve the problem. $z \to Az+c$ maps the line $l$ to the imaginary axis ($\text{Re}(w) = 0$). You can multiply with $i$ or $-i$ (or $13.5i$) to map the imaginary axis to the real axis. The final result will always be the same.